# how to get Profile name of lastModifiedBy in fflib selector class

Tags: apex, fflib

I'm facing issue that when I add LastModifiedBy profile name is getting in soql but when query it in fflib then is getting empty list

```
public List<Order> selectOrderIdsByProfileName(Set<Id> orderIdSet){
    return Database.query(
        newQueryFactory()
            .selectField('Id')
            .selectField('Approval_Status__c')
            .selectField('LastModifiedBy.ProfileId')
            .selectField('LastModifiedBy.Profile.Name')
            .setCondition('Id IN : orderIdSet')
            .toSOQL()
    );
}
```

Comment: Please stop adding random tags to your questions. Tags are meant to help convey what a question contains, what it's about. Tags also help people with knowledge find questions they may be able to answer. This doesn't appear to have anything to do with triggers or sfdx.

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community.  Are you saying that adding the line `.selectField('LastModifiedBy.Profile.Name')` -- the query returns no rows but if that line is omitted, the query returns rows?

Comment: @cropredy ,Yes ,the query returns no rows but if that line is omitted, the query returns rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your selector method is misnamed per fflib conventions

You have:

```
 public List<Order> selectOrderIdsByProfileName(Set<Id> orderIdSet){..}
```

You want:

```
 public List<Order> selectByOrderId(Set<Id> orderIdSet){...}
```

If you don't want the Queryfactory to use the fields defined in the selector class concrete method `getSobjectFieldList()` method, you need to tell the query factory to ignore these:

```
public List<Order> selectByOrderId(Set<Id> orderIdSet){
    return Database.query(
        newQueryFactory(false) // <= false - ignore selector default field names
            .selectField('Id')
            .selectField('LastModifiedBy.ProfileId')
            .selectField('LastModifiedBy.Profile.Name')
            .setCondition('Id IN : orderIdSet')
            .toSOQL()
    );
}
```

With this, when I execute:

```
 Order[] results = new OrdersSelector().selectByOrderId
                        (new Map<Id,SObject> (
                            [SELECT Id FROM Order Limit 2]).keySet());
 for (Order o: results) {
   System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,o.Id + ' ' + o.LastModifiedBy.Profile.Name);
 }
```

yields in the debug log:

```
SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[97]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, LastModifiedBy.Profile.Name, LastModifiedBy.ProfileId 
       FROM Order 
       WHERE Id IN : orderIdSet ORDER BY OrderNumber ASC NULLS FIRST
SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[97]|Rows:2

INFO|80103000001nd61AAA System Administrator
INFO|80103000001nd62AAA System Administrator
```

Query is constructed properly.

So, your problem lies elsewhere ...

- Are you sure you are passing in an non-empty collection of OrderIds to the selector when the line `.selectField('LastModifiedBy.Profile.Name')` is included in your test?
- Does the running user have visibility to those orders (check Sharing Settings)? *(most likely reason)*
- Are you using the latest fflib repo code's `fflib_SObjectSelector` as super class to your selector class? Mine is at v51.0